# Elastica mapping of array of tags

Tags: symfony, elasticsearch, elastica

I'm trying to set an index of cities in my elasticsearch server 
each city has an array of tags, and I want to index these tags as an array
what I do: 
config.yml:

```
                        tags: {type:"string", boost: 3}
```

my document:

```
/**
 * @MongoDB\Collection
 */
protected $tokens=array();
```

Tag format :

```
"tags": ["Bindura", "Bindura Town", "Kimberley Reefs", "\u0411\u0438\u043d\u0434\u0443\u0440\u0430"],
```

when I run : fos:elastica:populate , I get

```
 Array to string conversion in....ODM/BundleNameDocumentCitiesHydrator.php
```

in that line I have :

```
/** @Field(type="string") */
        if (isset($data['tokens'])) {
            $value = $data['tokens'];
            $return = (string) $token;
            $this->class->reflFields['tokens']->setValue($document, $return);
            $hydratedData['tokens'] = $return;
```

How Can I fix this ? How can I index arrays in elasticaBundle , I have looked at the documentation and It doesn't seem I'm doing anything wrong ..